# Can I turn protect_from_forgery off for my entier Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, devise, csrf

I'm creating a Rails app to interact with an iOS app. All of my requests are passing/expecting JSON, so I'm experiencing CSRF problems when posting. I can turn off protect_from_forgery (not ideal) but I don't want to do so on a per controller basis because I'm using devise, and I'd have to subclass each controller. Is there a way to turn it off for the entire app or what's a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it works but i would have tried this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Comment: Or just remove protect_from_forgery from the application_controller.rb file :-)

Comment: Perfect. The comment is just what I needed.